# Change the database Externally and access that using code first

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have created a database using code first approach in entity framework. I have made some changes to the database externally like adding a new column and now in the code if i have to add some data to that column will that work in code first?

If yes, How to make it work?

Comment: yes, u can do it but before telling the best solution first how many columns does u have added and does u aware of migration in the database?

Comment: yeah i know what migrations are , and does the number of columns added play any role? like if i have added two or three or more I'll add-migration to it and it does its work right!

Comment: yes here i wanna know if those are 2 or 3 rows we can delete from db  and add through but if more the we will go for database first approach up update our class and  replace them and force changes to db

Comment: and about the `add some data` u can do it in migrations

Comment: with a simple sql qureys